# Access codebehind variable in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

How can I access the public variable which in *Sample.xaml.cs* file like asp.net `<%=VariableName%>`?

Comment: [This question may also be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable) since it is a bit more recent ...

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

- Add your variable as a resource from codebehind:

  ```
  myWindow.Resources.Add("myResourceKey", myVariable);
  ```

  Then you can access it from XAML:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource myResourceKey}"/>
  ```

  If you have to add it after the XAML gets parsed, you can use a `DynamicResource` above instead of `StaticResource`.
- Make the variable a property of something in your XAML.  Usually this works through the `DataContext`:

  ```
  myWindow.DataContext = myVariable;
  ```

  or

  ```
  myWindow.MyProperty = myVariable;
  ```

  After this, anything in your XAML can access it through a `Binding`:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyOfMyVariable}"/>
  ```

  or

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=MyProperty}"/>
  ```

Answer (score 27):

For binding, if `DataContext` is not in use, you can simply add this to the constructor of the code behind:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Using this, every property in the code becomes accessible to binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
```

Another way is to just give a name to the root element of the XAML:

```
x:Name="root"
```

Since the XAML is compiled as a partial class of the code-behind, we can access every property by name:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName="root" Path=PropertyName}"/>
```

Note: access is only available to properties; not to fields. `set;` and `get;` or `{Binding Mode = OneWay}` are necessary. If OneWay binding is used, the underlying data should implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*.

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me out. I couldn't use the DataContext method because I'm creating a user control, and if I set the data context within my control, then my control won't be able to get the datacontext of its parents when I use it in applications. Binding directly to the root gave me the same result I was looking for and leaves my control's data context untouched.

Comment: Thanks for "root" advice. It works despite properties of code-behind are not listed in visual binding designer which is bit confusing.

Answer (score 11):

For quick-and-dirty Windows in WPF, I prefer binding the DataContext of the Window to the window itself; this can all be done in XAML.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty2}" />
        <Button Content="Set Property Values" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProperty2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty2", typeof(string), typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyProperty1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty1", typeof(string), typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyProperty1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyProperty1Property); }
        set { SetValue(MyProperty1Property, value); }
    }

    public string MyProperty2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyProperty2Property); }
        set { SetValue(MyProperty2Property, value); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set MyProperty1 and 2
        this.MyProperty1 = "Hello";
        this.MyProperty2 = "World";
    }
}
```

In the above example, note the binding used in the `DataContext` property on the Window, this says "Set your data context to yourself". The two text blocks are bound to `MyProperty1` and `MyProperty2`, the event handler for the button will set these values, which will automatically propagate to the `Text` property of the two TextBlocks as the properties are Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 3):

It is also worth noting that a 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject. If you want to set a non DependencyProperty (eg. a normal property) on an object in XAML, then you will have to use Robert's first method of using resources in the code behind.

Answer (score 3):

`myWindow.xaml`

```
<Window
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=testString }" />
</Window>
```

`myWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class myWindow: Window
{
    public string testString { get; set; } = "This is a test string";

    public myWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Important**

- Set `Datacontext`
- `testString` **MUST** be `public`
- `testString` **MUST** be a `property` (have a `get` and `set`)