# Two Way Data Binding With a Dictionary in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, dictionary

I'd like to bind a `Dictionary<string, int>` to a `ListView` in WPF. I'd like to do this in such a way that the `Values` in the `Dictionary` get updated via the data binding mechanism. I don't want to change the `Keys` just the `Values`. I also don't care about adding new mappings to the `Dictionary`. I just want to update existing ones.

Setting the Dictionary as the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` doesn't accomplish this.  It doesn't work because the `ListView` uses the Enumerator to access the contents of the `Dictionary` and the elements of that enumeration are immutable `KeyValuePair` objects.

My current line of investigation attempts to use the `Keys` property. I assign this to the `ItemsSource` property of my `ListView`. This does allow me to display the `Keys` but I don't know enough about WPF's databinding mechanism to access the `Values` in the `Dictionary`.

I found this question: [Access codebehind variable in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666856/access-codebehind-variable-in-xaml) but still can't seem to bridge the gap.

Do any of you know how to make this approach work?
Does anyone have a better approach?

It seems like, as a last resort, I could build a custom object and stick it in a `List` from which I recreate/update my `Dictionary` but this seems like a way to circumvent the built-in data binding functionality rather than effectively utilize it.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use something like an ObservableDictionary with WPF?

Comment: How are you going to make it two way? Are they Values being displayed in a TextBox?

Comment: @Ray I have a custom editor for my Values. If I had an example with a TextBox, I'm sure I could make it meet my needs.

Comment: Can you point any good example of that with ObservableDictionary @Rauhotz

Answer (score 20):

I don't think you're going to be able to do what you'd like with a dictionary.

1. Because the Dictionary doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanged
2. Because it's not going to allow two way binding like you want.

I'm not sure if it fits your requirements exactly, but I would use an `ObservableCollection`, and a custom class.

I'm using a DataTemplate, to show how to make the binding on the values two way.

Of course in this implementation Key isn't used, so you could just use an `ObservableCollection<int>`

Custom Class

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Set ItemsSource

```
ObservableCollection<MyCustomClass> dict = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomClass>();
dict.Add(new MyCustomClass{Key = "test", Value = 1});
dict.Add(new MyCustomClass{ Key = "test2", Value = 2 });
listView.ItemsSource = dict;
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I'm actually less worried about propagating changes from the Dictionary into the ListView than I am about propagating changes from the ListView into the Dictionary. The INotify interfaces seem like they're concerned mostly with the former.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However I tried to a Dictionary binding correctly and couldn't get it to work, as you couldn't. Will see if anyone else has any suggestions.

Comment: MyCustomClass needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: What about ObservableDictionary? EDIT: that might be newer than this answer.

Comment: @OwenJohnson if the ObservableDictionary now solves the problem, you should then add a new answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little hacky, but I got it to work (assuming that I understand what you want).

I first created a view model class:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.data.Add(1, "One");
        this.data.Add(2, "Two");
        this.data.Add(3, "Three");
    }

    Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public IDictionary<int, string> Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
    }

    private KeyValuePair<int, string>? selectedKey = null;
    public KeyValuePair<int, string>? SelectedKey
    {
        get { return this.selectedKey; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedKey = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            if(null == this.SelectedKey)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return this.data[this.SelectedKey.Value.Key];
        }
        set
        {
            this.data[this.SelectedKey.Value.Key] = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler  PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(null != eh)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Key"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedKey}">
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The value of the `Data` property is bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`. As you state in the question, this results in using instances of `KeyValuePair<int, string>` as the data behind the `ListBox`. I set the `DisplayMemberPath` to `Key` so that the value of the key will be used as the displayed value for each item in the `ListBox`.

As you found, you can't just use the `Value` of the `KeyValuePair` as the data for the `TextBox`, since that is read only. Instead, the `TextBox` is bound to a property on the view model which can get and set the value for the currently selected key (which is updated by binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to another property on the view model). I had to make this property nullable (since `KeyValuePair` is a struct), so that the code could detect when there is no selection.

In my test app, this seems to result in edits to the `TextBox` propagating to the `Dictionary` in the view model.

Is that more or less what you are going for? It seems like it should be a bit cleaner, but I'm not sure if there is any way to do so.

Comment: my situation is slightly different. I want to show the Dictionary<string, float> items as multiple pairs of Label and Textbox. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @YukiSakura I'd start with an ItemsControl found to the dictionary, and set the item template to have a Label and a TextBox bound to the appropriate properties.

Comment: I tried, but there was error at runtime saying that 'cannot use TwoWay for a readonly KeyValuePair...'

Comment: @YukiSakura That's because the Value member of KeyValuePair is readonly. You can try binding to another property that just returns the value for a given key in the dictionary (like the SelectedValue property in the code in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just posting what I derived from the above.  You can place the below in a `ObservableCollection<ObservableKvp<MyKeyObject, MyValueObject>>`

Made the Key read-only as they key probably shouldn't be changed.  This needs Prism to work - or you can implement your own version of `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead

```
public class ObservableKvp<K, V> : BindableBase
{
    public K Key { get; }

    private V _value;
    public V Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _value, value); }
    }

    public ObservableKvp(K key, V value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Dictionary<string, int>
```

, can you have a

```
Dictionary<string, IntWrapperClass>?
```

Have IntWrapperClass implement INotifyPropertyCHanged. Then you can have a Listview/Listbox two-way bind to items in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that in my project using an observable dictionary implemented by dr.wpf [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/) and using as Value not a String but an object[].
In xaml i got something like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableDictionary}" >
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value[0], Mode=TwoWay}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TextBox_Drop"></TextBox>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```