# Observable dictionary not behaving as expected

Tags: c#

I want to have Dictionary that would be 'Observable' in order to throw events when its item changing (Remove or Add).

In other class I created such dictionary and set Binding to `ListBox.ItemsSourseProperty`.
The Binding work well. I can see the items.

But something is wrong: the event `PropertyChanged` always null.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

```
class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : 
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public new void Remove(TKey obj)
    {
        base.Remove(obj);

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Remove"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098663/general-observable-dictionary-class-for-databinding-wpf-c

Comment: be cautious when using the new keyword... because that method will only be called when the object is scoped and casted to ObservableDictionary.  Since the majority of the framework bindind model will cast it to IEnumerable, Add & Remove will still call the downstream implementation on the base Dictionary.

I would instead write your class as a wrapper class that has an internal Dictionary for storage and then implement the IDictionary & INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces and corresponding methods.

Comment: public class Foo
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
        }
    }

    public class Foo2 : Foo
    {
        public new void Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2");
        }
    }

var f = new Foo2();
f.Bar();
((Foo)f).Bar();

Returns 
Test 2
Test 1

Comment: take a look into http://observabledic.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call `PropertyChanged` for a collection change event. You need to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you subscribe the `PropertyChanged` event?

```
var dictionary = new ObservableDictionary<int, int>();
dictionary.PropertyChanged += 
    ( sender, args ) => MessageBox.Show( args.PropertyName );
dictionary.Add( 1, 2 );
dictionary.Remove( 1 );
```

This works for me.

But it would be cleaner to implement the interface `IDictionary` instead of using the `new` keyword. Then you can use a private *Dictionary* instance within your class to safe you the work of implementing everything on your own.

Comment: Works for me also....BTW you should check that base.Remove(obj) actually removes something :)

Comment: I set Binding to itemsSource of control.
Is not Binding register automatically to PropertyChanged ?

Comment: @yossharel, no, for ItemsSource it's subscribing to INotifyCollectionChanged

Answer (score 2):

Is anyone subscribing to Propertychanged?

For an observable collection, you are going to also want INotifyCollectionChanged

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may be looking for a dictionary version of `ObservableCollection` (see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)), which implements both `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` out of the box.  Perhaps looking over its implementation in reflector may be helpful?  It  can be found in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace in the System.dll assembly.