# .NET ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection, dictionary

I have written the following class which implements(or tries to!) a dictionary with notifications:

```
public partial class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public ObservableDictionary() : base() { }
    public ObservableDictionary(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(comparer) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) : base(dictionary) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(capacity, comparer) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(dictionary, comparer) { }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, key, 0));
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, key, 0));
    }

    public new bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        bool x = base.Remove(key);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, key, 0));
        return x;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

In another class, I have a listener for the `MyObservableDictionary.CollectionChanged` event:

The problem I'm having is that the event doesn't fire. How can I fix this?

Comment: does "onCollectionChanged" not fire, or does "collectionChanged" not fire?

Comment: Provide the event listener class ..

Comment: In addition to @Tim..'s question, can you show the code in the consumer where you are assigning a delegate method to the event handler?

Comment: @Tim, @Akram : tc.EventHistory.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(EventHistory_CollectionChanged); where tc is the usercontrol containing the ObservableDictionary(callede EventHistory). Also @Tim OnCollectionChanged doesn't fire

Comment: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/binding-to-a-dictionary-in-wpf-and-silverlight

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'd suggest that you implement the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of inheriting from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Since you have to use `new` rather than `override` it's possible that the methods are simply being called on the base class rather than your class. I'd be tempted to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` internally to do the actual storing of data.

In fact I found this:
 http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx

Comment: using xaml how do you bind the SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue?

Comment: Unfortunately, the blogpost doesn't seem to specify under which license terms the code may be used.

Answer (score 56):

The Microsoft ParallelExtensionsExtras provides this class which is not only observable but is also concurrent:

Now available via Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/

The source code was recently [updated for .NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-extensions-extras-cs/) on 05/11/2020 and the source code is available at GitHub:
https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/csharp/parallel/ParallelExtensionsExtras

Note that some of the features are now a part of newer .NET frameworks.
[Are the ParallelExtensions "Extras" still of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494157/are-the-parallelextensions-extras-still-of-value)

Microsoft Tour Blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/04/a-tour-of-parallelextensionsextras/

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 
// 
//  File: ObservableConcurrentDictionary.cs
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace System.Collections.Concurrent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a thread-safe dictionary for use with data binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">Specifies the type of the keys in this collection.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">Specifies the type of the values in this collection.</typeparam>
    [DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
    public class ObservableConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
        INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an instance of the ObservableConcurrentDictionary class.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableConcurrentDictionary()
        {
            _context = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
            _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        /// <summary>Event raised when the collection changes.</summary>
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        /// <summary>Event raised when a property on the collection changes.</summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies observers of CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged of an update to the dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        private void NotifyObserversOfChange()
        {
            var collectionHandler = CollectionChanged;
            var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
            if (collectionHandler != null || propertyHandler != null)
            {
                _context.Post(s =>
                {
                    if (collectionHandler != null)
                    {
                        collectionHandler(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                    }
                    if (propertyHandler != null)
                    {
                        propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                        propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                        propertyHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
                    }
                }, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item to be added.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryAddWithNotification(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return TryAddWithNotification(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value of the item to be added.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryAddWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            bool result = _dictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
            if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange();
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to remove an item from the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be removed.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value of the item removed.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the removal was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryRemoveWithNotification(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            bool result = _dictionary.TryRemove(key, out value);
            if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange();
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to add or update an item in the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be updated.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The new value to set for the item.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the update was successful.</returns>
        private void UpdateWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            _dictionary[key] = value;
            NotifyObserversOfChange();
        }

        #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            TryAddWithNotification(item);
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
        {
            ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Clear();
            NotifyObserversOfChange();
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Contains(item);
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        int ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Count
        {
            get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Count; }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).IsReadOnly; }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            TValue temp;
            return TryRemoveWithNotification(item.Key, out temp);
        }
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members
        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members
        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            TryAddWithNotification(key, value);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys
        {
            get { return _dictionary.Keys; }
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            TValue temp;
            return TryRemoveWithNotification(key, out temp);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        public ICollection<TValue> Values
        {
            get { return _dictionary.Values; }
        }

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get { return _dictionary[key]; }
            set { UpdateWithNotification(key, value); }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: This line occurs error: `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }`

Comment: I've used the code and it works.  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Error message: `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: replace that with:        `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }`

Comment: I can't get to call `.Clear()` because it doesnt exist. Any ideas?

Comment: .clear has been part if icollection since DotNET 2.0.  It likely is a problem on the icollection type you are using and not this code.  Are you using this on a custom icollection class or on one of the built-in types?

Comment: A nice addition would be to return the "Keys" and "Values" as an ObservableCollection as well, or some other collection that implements INotifyPropertyChanged/INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: You can!  It's generic, so just specify this during implementation/instantiation.  If you want to force this behavior, create a derived/inherited class that narrows the definition.

Comment: Depending on the usage, you may want to make _context.Post(...) use _context.Send(...) instead for synchronous event handling.  I ran into race conditions trying to use it asynchronously.

Comment: To notify only Resets does not correctly fulfill the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Comment: @Korayem To get access to the `Clear` method you must cast the dictionary to the `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. I'd suggest using a following extension method: `public static ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> AsCollection<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
return dictionary;
}`

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia yeah I second that

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia and Matthew ... correct collection notifications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary/54503237#54503237)

Comment: I appreciate the commentary.  I was pasting the source code that is part of the NuGet package.

Comment: thank you @VoteCoffee,  I installed ParallelExtensionsExtras, simply use ObservableConcurrentDictionary under using System.Collections.Concurrent;
, then bumps, it works =]

Answer (score 14):

Your solution - Fixed ;)

```
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public ObservableDictionary( ) : base( ) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(comparer) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) : base(dictionary) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(capacity, comparer) { }
    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : base(dictionary, comparer) { }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public new TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            return base[key];
        }
        set {
            TValue oldValue;
            bool exist = base.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue);
            var oldItem = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, oldValue);
            base[key] = value;
            var newItem = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
            if (exist) {
                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, newItem, oldItem, base.Keys.ToList( ).IndexOf(key)));
            } else {
                this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newItem, base.Keys.ToList( ).IndexOf(key)));
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
            }
        }
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
        if (!base.ContainsKey(key)) {
            var item = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
            base.Add(key, value);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, base.Keys.ToList( ).IndexOf(key)));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
        }
    }

    public new bool Remove(TKey key) {
        TValue value;
        if (base.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
            var item = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, base[key]);
            bool result = base.Remove(key);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, base.Keys.ToList( ).IndexOf(key)));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public new void Clear( ) {
        base.Clear( );
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null) {
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why this class is `partial`?

Comment: @MasterMastic: you would have to ask the OP that question. Marciej provided the class declaration the same as the OP.

Comment: @MasterMastic there is no reason to use partial.

Comment: in your remove function you have to query the key before you remove the item from the dictionary or else the key will always be -1 :)

Comment: Is it working in the case of an initialization? `Dic = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>(){ {"1", "First"} };` ?

Comment: @Cfun It supports all standard dictionary initialization, I tested it is also valid solution for new .NET 5.0. However with new C# we could improve the syntax of the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I rolled out my own: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/hellosam.net.collections/

It uses AVL tree so operations are O(log N) instead, where most implementations I have seen using List.indexOf() are O(N).

It can even observe your item INotifyPropertyChanged and convert them to a observable collection event, so to keep the DataGrid sort/group response to the change.

Comment: nuget package missing BinaryTree.cs

Also, enumerator enumerates values instead of key value pairs which is atypical for dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignatio and Matthew pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26676294/152997) answer, only raising the `Reset` collection change notification is incorrect, and not very useful if the caller needs to know what actually changed. Fortunately it is easily corrected. Note this version uses `Send` instead of `Post` as Nathan mentioned in the earlier answer, because WPF is sensitive to reporting back the correct index upon removal, and getting it wrong yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883870/) confusing exception. (*Caveat emptor: I'm still not completely convinced the reported index will be fully reliable if there are many overlapping changes, especially given that Dictionaries should be treated as un-ordered.*)

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. 
// 
//  File: ObservableConcurrentDictionary.cs
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace System.Collections.Concurrent
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a thread-safe dictionary for use with data binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">Specifies the type of the keys in this collection.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">Specifies the type of the values in this collection.</typeparam>
    [DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
    public class ObservableConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
        INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes an instance of the ObservableConcurrentDictionary class.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableConcurrentDictionary()
        {
            _context = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
            _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        /// <summary>Event raised when the collection changes.</summary>
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        /// <summary>Event raised when a property on the collection changes.</summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies observers of CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged of an update to the dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        private void NotifyObserversOfChange()
        {
            var collectionHandler = CollectionChanged;
            var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
            if (collectionHandler != null || propertyHandler != null)
            {
                _context.Send(s =>
                {
                    collectionHandler?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
                }, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies observers of CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged of an update to the dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionType">Add or Update action</param>
        /// <param name="changedItem">The item involved with the change</param>
        private void NotifyObserversOfChange(NotifyCollectionChangedAction actionType, object changedItem)
        {
            var collectionHandler = CollectionChanged;
            var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
            if (collectionHandler != null || propertyHandler != null)
            {
                _context.Send(s =>
                {
                    collectionHandler?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(actionType, changedItem));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
                }, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies observers of CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged of an update to the dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionType">Remove action or optionally an Add action</param>
        /// <param name="item">The item in question</param>
        /// <param name="index">The position of the item in the collection</param>
        private void NotifyObserversOfChange(NotifyCollectionChangedAction actionType, object item, int index)
        {
            var collectionHandler = CollectionChanged;
            var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
            if (collectionHandler != null || propertyHandler != null)
            {
                _context.Send(s =>
                {
                    collectionHandler?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(actionType, item, index));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Keys"));
                    propertyHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
                }, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item to be added.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryAddWithNotification(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            => TryAddWithNotification(item.Key, item.Value);

        /// <summary>Attempts to add an item to the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be added.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value of the item to be added.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the add was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryAddWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            bool result = _dictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
            int index = IndexOf(key);
            if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, value, index);
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to remove an item from the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be removed.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value of the item removed.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the removal was successful.</returns>
        private bool TryRemoveWithNotification(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            int index = IndexOf(key);
            bool result = _dictionary.TryRemove(key, out value);
            if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, value, index);
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>Attempts to add or update an item in the dictionary, notifying observers of any changes.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key of the item to be updated.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The new value to set for the item.</param>
        /// <returns>Whether the update was successful.</returns>
        private void UpdateWithNotification(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            _dictionary[key] = value;
            NotifyObserversOfChange(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// WPF requires that the reported index for Add/Remove events are correct/reliable. With a dictionary there
        /// is no choice but to brute-force search through the key list. Ugly.
        /// </summary>
        private int IndexOf(TKey key)
        {
            var keys = _dictionary.Keys;
            int index = -1;
            foreach(TKey k in keys)
            {
                index++;
                if (k.Equals(key)) return index;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        // ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members


        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            => TryAddWithNotification(item);

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
        {
            _dictionary.Clear();
            NotifyObserversOfChange();
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).Contains(item);

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
            => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

        int ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Count
        {
            get => _dictionary.Count;
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
        {
            get => ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)_dictionary).IsReadOnly;
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            => TryRemoveWithNotification(item.Key, out TValue temp);


        // IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members


        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
            => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();


        // IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members


        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
            => TryAddWithNotification(key, value);

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
            => _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys
        {
            get { return _dictionary.Keys; }
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
            => TryRemoveWithNotification(key, out TValue temp);

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
            => _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

        public ICollection<TValue> Values
        {
            get => _dictionary.Values;
        }

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get => _dictionary[key];
            set => UpdateWithNotification(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These collections are probably a better option: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Answer (score -3):

I have managed to find a solution - workaround

```
public delegate void CollectionAlteredEventHander( object sender , EventArgs e);

public partial class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{

    /*Class contructors*/

    public event CollectionAlteredEventHander CollectionAltered;

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            OnCollectionAltered(new EventArgs());
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        int idx = 0;
        if (!TryGetKeyIndex(this, key, ref idx))
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
            OnCollectionAltered(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public new bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        int idx = 0; 
        if( TryGetKeyIndex( this ,key, ref idx))
        {
            OnCollectionAltered(new EventArgs());
            return base.Remove(key);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool TryGetKeyIndex(ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> observableDictionary, TKey key , ref int idx)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in observableDictionary) 
        {
            if (pair.Key.Equals(key)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        OnCollectionAltered(new EventArgs());
        base.Clear();            
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionAltered(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionAltered != null)
        {
            CollectionAltered(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

I've no longer implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface though.