# Base class for implementing own dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

If I need my own IList(T), but don't want to implement it from scratch, I can inherit from

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
```

which will allow me to customize addition, removal, and clear operations.
But what should I do if I want exactly the same for

```
IDictionary<T1, T2>
```

?

Comment: IDictionary specifies just six methods. Which ones don't you want to implement yourself?

Comment: Implement the interface `IDictionary<>` using a `Dictionary<>` (or `SortedDictionary<>` etc) as private field. Inheriting from `Dictionary<>` is discouraged...

Comment: @DavidArno: According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx), `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` specifies 5 properties and 10 methods - and that is not counting the additional ones that require explicit interface implementations, such as [`System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx).

Comment: In what way do you want to customise them? It is not possible to advise you unless we know what you are attempting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, my bad. I didn't read the question properly and missed the fact the OP was refering to the generic version of IDictionary. That does make a huge difference!

Comment: @Alex B, I'd like it to be redundant. As a fan of SOLID and an advocate of viewing inheritance as a code smell, I dislike .NET's collections. I'd therefore move mountains to avoid having to create my own implementation of IDictionary<T1,T2>. However, this doesn't help solve your problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET ObservableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary)

Answer (score 3):

Why not create an implementation of `IDictionary<TKey,TVal>` that delegates method calls onto an internally held `Dictionary<TKey,TVal>`? Then you can change the behaviour in any way you see fit!

```
public class MyCustomDictionary<TKey,TVal>:IDictionary<TKey,TVal>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TVal> dictionary;

    public MyCustomDictionary()
    {
        dictionary=new Dictionary<TKey, TVal>();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((ICollection) dictionary).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection) dictionary).SyncRoot; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection) dictionary).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    public bool Contains(object key)
    {
        return ((IDictionary) dictionary).Contains(key);
    }

    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        ((IDictionary) dictionary).Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Remove(object key)
    {
        ((IDictionary) dictionary).Remove(key);
    }

    public object this[object key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[(TKey) key]; }
        set { dictionary[(TKey) key] = (TVal) value; }
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return ((IDictionary) dictionary).IsFixedSize; }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TVal value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> item)
    {
        TVal v;
        return (dictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out v) && v.Equals(item.Key));
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>>)dictionary)
            .CopyTo(array,arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal> item)
    {
        if (Contains(item))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(item.Key);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TVal value)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsValue(value);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        dictionary.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        dictionary.OnDeserialization(sender);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return dictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TVal value)
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public IEqualityComparer<TKey> Comparer
    {
        get { return dictionary.Comparer; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }

    public TVal this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key]; }
        set { dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return dictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public ICollection<TVal> Values
    {
        get { return dictionary.Values; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TVal>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey,TVal> item)
    {
        dictionary.Add(item.Key,item.Value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, Resharper eats this kind of problem for dinner.

Comment: Yes, it's the most obvious way to do it, but existence of System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T> and absence of something similar for IDictionary seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: Well, a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is an implementation of `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, but I'd venture that using this as a starting point would be misguided.