# How to notify\raise event when a key value is added to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to perform some action in an other thread if a new key\value pair is added to static dictionary. One naïve method is to do polling at frequent intervals and check if ContainsKey(givenKey), but I want to do even more quicker instead of delay in polling.

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary. I don't believe there's anything built into the framework. (There are lots of third party implementations though.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. We end up creating custom dictionary to get done this simple thing. Would be good if built into framework!

Comment: @RahulSundar oh, i`ve read your comment to late ): But maybe i provide some more information :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create your own Dictionary. Best practice would be:

```
public enum Type
{
    AddItem,
    RemoveItem
}

public class DictChangedEventArgs<K, V> : EventArgs
{
    public Type Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public K Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public V Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class OwnDict<K, V> : IDictionary<K, V>
{
    public delegate void DictionaryChanged(object sender, DictChangedEventArgs<K, V> e);

    public event DictionaryChanged OnDictionaryChanged;

    private IDictionary<K, V> innerDict;

    public OwnDict()
    {
        innerDict = new Dictionary<K, V>();
    }

    public void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        if (OnDictionaryChanged != null)
        {
            OnDictionaryChanged(this, new DictChangedEventArgs<K, V>() { Type = Type.AddItem, Key = key, Value = value });
        }

        innerDict.Add(key, value);
    }

    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Now you are free to create event for `Before-Add-Item`, `After-Add-Item`. You can also add some `Handled` parameter to your `DictChangedEventArgs`-Class to prevent adding a special item. You can also decide to work with the `Type`-Enum or create an own event for every action.

But be sure, you have to implement all methods from `IDictionary`, but this should be very easy.

Comment: I see that you raise the event before you add the item to the dictionary, I believe this would then constitute a better naming convention of "PreviewChange" or something synonymously equivalent. Good answer though! +1

Comment: @Krythic yeah, that is true. Even better would be both. So that it would be possible to cancel adding by using the event args of the ..Preview event.

Comment: A few years later...been busy, my dude? Lol.