# Update Single Item in the ObservableCollection without LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am trying to create a list of the `Components` running on the network. I am trying to get all the components in the `ObservableCollection`. `ObservableCollection<ClsComponent>` Now my question is if one of the component in the collection get changed / modified how would I be able to get it reflected to my `ObservableCollection` of Component

1. Is there a way to change the it directly in the collection itself?
2. What is the fast and efficient way doing it?

I have tried: to change it using the **LINQ** : Find the `Component` in the collection and change it?

```
var CompFound = Components.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == myId);
Components.Remove(CompFound);
Components.Add(UpdatedComp);
```

I am very sure there should have been more optimized way of doing this. Please suggest.

**Edit**

I am trying to write the code in the function where I can get the parameters of `Source Component` and `Destination Component`. Function looks like this

```
public void UpdateComponent(ClsComponent SourceComp, ClsComponent DestComp)
{
  //do something here 
}
```

After the execution of the function I want to Replace Source Component with Destination Component.

Comment: You mean to say you wanted to change the Collection Directly?

Comment: Yes @MohitShrivastava I want to change it directly like in case of remove. Just need to call Collection.Remove(Obj) something of that sort

Comment: What you're doing there is replacing an existing item with a new one and not at the same index.  Are you saying that you want to make changes to the existing item instead of doing the replacement?

Comment: By the way, you're misusing `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes both the statements are correct. I want to change an existing component but doing a replacement since I get the Updated Component in the form of Object of ClsComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might work for you. I am sure you might be looking for this

```
Components.Insert(Components.IndexOf(SourceComp), DestComp);
Components.Remove(SourceComp);
```

Comment: Amazing. It works like the way I wanted. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @DollyShrivastava

Answer (score 0):

One of the most efficient way would be to use a dictionary. There are implementations of ObservableDictionary which will give you the Observable behavior while allowing a fast key-based access to the object.
Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary). It includes Microsoft's

It should work like ObservableCollection, except it's also a dictionary. So you can Create `ObservableDictionary<Int,ClsComponent>`

To replace the value simply call

```
Components[myId] = destComp
```

Comment: Nice link provided. Still in my case I dont want to use `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Updated my answer. You don't need to use INotifyCollectionChanged to replace the value. A dictionary is also faster than indexOf if you have more than [3 items](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time)