# Dictionary Data Change Notification

Tags: c#, dictionary, propertychanged

I have a situation where I need to monitor and react to changes to objects in a dictionary.

```
class Order
{
  string Ordernumber;
  string Orderstate;
  int Shares;
  decimal Price;
}
```

For Example:

```
Dictionary<string, Order> OrderData = new Dictionary<string, Order>
```

When for example OrderState changes in the Order Class what would be the best way to 
raise a property change for that specific entry in the Dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary) A custom observable dictionary is what you are looking for. This will allow you to monitor collection and it's object state without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: @vendettamit Thanks that's pretty much what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @vendettamit For sure!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom observable dictionary is what you are looking for. And There's no built-in observable dictionary available. So you need to write down few bits. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary) for implementation of Observable dictionary.

The custom dictionary will allow you to monitor collection and it's object state without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for Order as described in this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx