# Two-way databinding for a dictionary in UWP/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I currently have an application where I'm parsing a YAML dictionary.  I have a model named `Line` that looks like this -

```
    public class Line
    {

        private ObservableDictionary<string, string> language = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();

        public Line()
        {
            Language = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        // used with the YAML parser
        [YamlMember(Alias = "language")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Language { get; set; }

    }
```

You've probably noticed that I'm using an `ObservableDictionary`, which is not a standard type.  I took the code from this [other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14410196/2584408).  As I understand it, it's just setting up the necessary `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Anyway, for my `Line`, I have a `ListView` populated with a dictionary of translations represented as the language abbreviation and a textbox.  To better exemplify what I'm talking about, here is a graphic.

[image]

In my `App.xaml`, I have a `DataTemplate` for my ListView defined - together, they look like this:

```
<ListView 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LinesTemplateItem}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Value.Language}" 
    SelectionMode="None">
</ListView>

...

<DataTemplate x:Key="LinesTemplateItem">
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Everything seems like it should work fine.  My data shows properly.  However, when I change a value, it does not update the underlying source with the error:

```
Error: Cannot save value from target back to source. 
BindingExpression: Path='Value' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.Collections.IKeyValuePair`2<String,String>'; 
target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' (Name='null'); 
target property is 'Text' (type 'String').
```

From the error, I would guess that for some reason the databinding is targeting the entire UI control instead of the text inside of it.  I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this error.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the property `IKeyValuePair.Value` is read-only so you cannot modify it. My proposition is to change you data model a little bit i.e. firstly create an additional class to store translations.

```
public class Translation
{
   public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should also change a definition of your dictionary e.g.:

```
public Dictionary<string, Translation> Language { get; set; }
```

Binding should be also updated accordingly:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value.Expression, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Thanks to that if you change a value, the data binding will update `Expression` property which is not read-only.

I didn't test this code but I did similar things in the past so something like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're binding to `Dictionary<string,string>`, each item is bound to `KeyValuePair<string,string>`, which is of value type - it's fields cannot be changed (while unboxed). You should bind to the pair itself, rather than its parts and use value converter to produce a pair with changed value.