# How to trigger reload of combobox itemsource

Tags: xaml, combobox, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have a combobox and I am binding the combobox in XAML with viewmodel dictionary values.

When the page is loaded for first time I am trying to download the dictionary values and from server and set it to the dictionary view model variable.

But the combobox looks empty I don't understand why this happens because View Model variable has been updated and thats supposed to trigger the reload of combobox and thats not happening..

FYI:
If I hardcode the dictionary rather than downloading it from server I don't see this problem
When I load the page second time I don't see this problem

**Update**

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name=“testBox” Margin=“0,0,0,0” PlaceholderText="{StaticResource testText}” ItemsSource="{Binding TestDictionary.Values}” SelectedValue="{Binding DictionaryValue, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsItLoading, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

View Model

```
       private Dictionary<string, string> testDictionary;


 public Dictionary<string, string> TestDictionary
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.testDictionary == null)
                {
                    this.testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }

                return this.testDictionary;
            }

            set
            {
                this.Set(() => this.TestDictionary, ref this.testDictionary, value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your `ViewModel` and `XAML` how you are assigning the data to Combobox?

Comment: @AVK - I have updated my code sample in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` does not provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the entire list is refreshed.

When we add new data to the `Dictionary`, we should be able to set `null` to the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`. Then set the `TestDictionary.Values` to `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`.

You can also implemented your own `ObservableDictionary`. When the `Dictionary` changes, the `ComboBox` will be changed.
To implement the `ObservableDictionary`, you can refer the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary).