# How to reference a struct's type parameters in a generic C# class?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I would like to create my own implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` but I want the observable collection to be a dictionary. Something like:

```
MyObservableDictionary<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

After reading [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379564(v=vs.80)#generic-constraints) about generics it seems that you can define that as

```
public class MyObservableDictionary<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged where T : struct
{
  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

but this

1. does not enforces that the struct should be of type
   KeyValuePair and
2. I don't know how to reference `TKey` and `TValue` in the class.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: `public class MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged where TValue : struct {...}` - class which is dictionary, observable and can have value type (`strict`) as value only. Add `where TKey : struct` if you want key be a struct as well

Comment: There are several examples of `ObservableDictionary` implementations, why create it on your own? Links: [stackoverflow - .NET ObservableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary), [Github - kzu/ObservableDictionary.cs](https://gist.github.com/kzu/cfe3cb6e4fe3efea6d24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,  you have `2` generic parameters, let them be `TKey` and `TValue`:

```
public class MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Your class implements *two interfaces*:

1. "I want the ... collection to be a *dictionary*" - `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`
2. "I would like to create my own implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged`"

Add them:

```
public class MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
  : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged
```

Finally, if I've understood you right, you want to *restrict* both `TKey` and `TValue` to be `struct` only; you can do it with a help of `where`:

```
 public class MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
  : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged 
  where TKey : struct
  where TValue : struct {
  //TODO: implementation here
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that ` where TValue : struct where TKey : struct` means that TKey would be a struct and TValue another one and I want the generic struct `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`?

Comment: If I've understood you *right*, you want `TKey` and `TValue` be `struct`, e.g. `MyObservableDictionary<int, double>`, but not `MyObservableDictionary<int, object>` (`object` is not `struct`). Please, not that  `TKey` and `TValue` can be *arbitrary* `struct`, not necessary the same.

Comment: Probably my bad Dmitry, I wanted `TKey` and `TValue` to be parameters of a struct. That's the struct that I want `KeyValuePair<Tkey,TValue>`.

Comment: @Themelis: `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a *private affair* of  the dictionary; you don't have to put any constraint on it. Current .Net (4.8) implements `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue` as a `struct`, next can well turn it into `class`. `TKey`,`TValue` are the only matter: if you want to put constraint(s) on them - add `where`. Please, not that any type, say, `int` can be a part of `struct` as well as part of `class`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
MyObservableDictionairy<TKey, TValue> : INotifyCollectionChanged where TValue : struct
```

You can then wrap the key/values into key/value pairs as they are added, or simply have an add method signature like this:

```
public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value)
```