# ObservableDictionary for c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to use following implementation of the ObservableDictionary: [ObservableDictionary (C#)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx).

When I'm using following code while binding the dictionary to a DataGrid:

```
ObserveableDictionary<string,string> dd=new ObserveableDictionary<string,string>();
....
dd["aa"]="bb";
....
dd["aa"]="cc";
```

at `dd["aa"]="cc";` I'm getting following exception

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the 
collection. Parameter name: index
```

This exception  is thrown in `CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem)` in the following method:

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
{
  OnPropertyChanged();

  if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem));
}
```

The `index` param seems to correspond to `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem`.

How can `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` be out of range, and what should I do to make this work?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kzu/cfe3cb6e4fe3efea6d24 this here seems pretty good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar data structure, to bind to Dictionary type collection

http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

It provides a new Data structure ObservableDictionary and fires [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) in case of any change to underlying Dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

here's what I did in the end:

```
[Serializable]
public class ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region properties
    private TKey key;
    private TValue value;

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set
        {
            key = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Key");
        }
    }

    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey,TValue>:ObservableCollection<ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>, IDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{

    #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The dictionary already contains the key");
        }
        base.Add(new ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>() {Key = key, Value = value});
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        //var m=base.FirstOrDefault((i) => i.Key == key);
        var r = ThisAsCollection().FirstOrDefault((i) => Equals(key, i.Key));

        return !Equals(default(ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>), r);
    }

    bool Equals<TKey>(TKey a, TKey b)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(a, b);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ThisAsCollection()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return (from i in ThisAsCollection() select i.Key).ToList(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        var remove = ThisAsCollection().Where(pair => Equals(key, pair.Key)).ToList();
        foreach (var pair in remove)
        {
            ThisAsCollection().Remove(pair);
        }
        return remove.Count > 0;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        value = default(TValue);
        var r = GetKvpByTheKey(key);
        if (!Equals(r, default(ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        value = r.Value;
        return true;
    }

    private ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> GetKvpByTheKey(TKey key)
    {
        return ThisAsCollection().FirstOrDefault((i) => i.Key.Equals(key));
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return (from i in ThisAsCollection() select i.Value).ToList(); }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue result;
            if (!TryGetValue(key,out result))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key not found");
            }
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ContainsKey(key))
            {
                GetKvpByTheKey(key).Value = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var r = GetKvpByTheKey(item.Key);
        if (Equals(r, default(ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals(r.Value, item.Value);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var r = GetKvpByTheKey(item.Key);
        if (Equals(r, default(ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Equals(r.Value,item.Value))
        {
            return false ;
        }
        return ThisAsCollection().Remove(r);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members

    public new IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (from i in ThisAsCollection() select new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(i.Key, i.Value)).ToList().GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This implementation looks and feels like dictionary to the user and like ObservableCollection to WPF

Comment: IMO its not good (for large data), because main purpose of dictionary is not to store, but to do fast retrieval using hashing techniques. [this link](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)  has true ObservableDictionary with fast retrieval. (as ObservableDictionary wraps over Dictionary)

Comment: Nice job! In `TryGetValue`, the if statement should be `if (Equals(r, default(ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)))`

Comment: Nathan, you are right. It was giving me KeyNotFoundException

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a class to hold the Key-Value pair and using a collection of that class. I'm using Caliburn Micro which is where the BindableCollection comes from, but an ObservableCollection should work the same way. I use the MVVM pattern.

the viewmodel

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

private BindableCollection<KeyValuePair> _items;

public BindableCollection<KeyValuePair> Items
{
  get { return _items; }

  set
  {
    if (_items != value)
    {
      _items = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
    }
  }
}
```

the custom keyValuePair

```
public class KeyValuePair 
{
  public string Key { get; set; }

  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                 Text="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It bothers me that I can't just bind to a dictionary, but I find this much easier and cleaner than writing an ObservableDictionary from scratch and worrying about the change notifications.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableDictionary was added to the .Net Framework at version 4.5:-

https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/observabledictionary-in-net-4-5/

Here is a link to the latest source code:-

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Annotations/ObservableDictionary.cs

Comment: Do you see it's `internal` ?

Answer (score 0):

install Microsoft ParallelExtensionsExtras

Now available via Nuget:
nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras
that library implements ObservableConcurrentDictionary, I tried and it works =]

Note that some of the features are now a part of newer .NET frameworks. Are the ParallelExtensions "Extras" still of value?

Microsoft Tour Blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/04/a-tour-of-parallelextensionsextras/

FYR, from
[.NET ObservableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary)
[General Observable Dictionary Class for DataBinding/WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098663/general-observable-dictionary-class-for-databinding-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

I first created a class called "ConcurrentObservableCollection" in which i extended the ObservableCollection functions.

```
public class ConcurrentObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public new void Add(T value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            base.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var copyList = new List<T>();
            copyList.AddRange(base.Items);
            return copyList;
        }
    }

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return base.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return base.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public new void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            base.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
        }
    }

    public new bool Contains(T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return base.Contains(item);
        }
    }

    public new void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            base.Insert(index, item);
        }
    }

    public new int Count()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return base.Count;
        }
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            base.Clear();
        }
    }

    public new T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return base[index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then i replaced the exisitng "ObservabeCollection" with my new "ConcurrentObservableCollection"

Answer (score -2):

Even I am using the ObservableDictionary of github, I also faced this exception. I had declared the dictionary variable at class level later I tried to create a new instance in the method where it was getting accessed.

OldCode which gave exception:

```
public class CName
{
  ObservableDictionary<string, string> _classVariableDictionary = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();
}
```

NewCode which worked:

```
public void MethodName()
{
    ObservableDictionary<string, string> _localVariableDictionary = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();
}
```