# WPF Binding Dictionary to ItemsControl doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I need to show the Key values of a dictionary in my application so that you see on which step of the list you are. So I thought an itemscontrol would be the best choice to go with. It didn't work out well. The Binding seems not to work at all. I haven't found any solution on google that matches my problem, at all solution the general binding seems to work...

I have following code, to demonstrate that the binding should work correctly I tried the same with a DataGrid and a ListView, both work fine:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding WizardSteps}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key}" Header="Key" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding WizardSteps}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But this code doesn't work (no items):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WizardSteps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#:

```
public Dictionary<string, PageViewModelBase> WizardSteps { get; set; } = 
    new Dictionary<string, PageViewModelBase>();

private void _CreateWizardSteps()
{
    CreateWizardStepsSpecific(WizardSteps);
    WizardSteps.Add("Report", new ReportStepViewModel<ReportView>());
    WizardSteps.Add("Report1", new ReportStepViewModel<ReportView>());
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WizardSteps);
}
```

I can't explain this to me, shouldn't the itemscontrol work the same way as the listview?

Comment: What class belongs the C# code to? Is it code part of your window?

Comment: @stop-cran no it's the datacontext of the usercontrol

Comment: @ViVi the datagird works fine, the only problem is with the itemscontrol where no items appear.

Comment: What does the `ItemsControl` one produce? Does it not generate the two textblocks? Or maybe the textblocks are there without the texts?

Comment: I'm looking for solving it

Comment: @Jai The textblocks aren't there, I checked it with an additional textbox that had a static value.

Comment: What is your problem, because it works perfectly here.

Comment: "shouldn't the itemscontrol work the same way as the listview?" Yes, it should, and actually it does. There is probably something else in your code you haven't shown. As it stands now your problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @GuillaumeP. wtf... did you try my code? I'm trying this for several hours now and also can't explain to me why it's not working.

Comment: In case you are changing the dictionary after the bindings are created, you should use an [ObservableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10616554/1136211).

Comment: Do you have a Panel (Grid or something) wrapping the ItemsControl?

Comment: @HansDabi Yes I tried it, and It works, let me copy paste it as a response

Comment: @HansDabi As said above, you must use an observableCollection to inform view that item sources has been updated.

Comment: Not repro for me. Try to set a simple data context for the `ItemsControl` to clarify the issue - is it related to binding  or the context itself.

Comment: A workaround might be to create a new dictionary instance in _CreateWizardSteps() by `WizardSteps = new Dictionary<string, PageViewModelBase>();`.

Comment: @Clemens yes but it's not the best to way to achieve on. On a few list of items it works, but on a huge collection :/

Comment: @Clemens you're right. it was just to inform him about weakness of this. It is a good workaround instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to use an ObservableDictionary instead of a normal one. Doesn't explain to me why it worked with the DataGrid and the ListView but the point is I solved it :) 
Thanks to all who helped me.

Comment: A possible explanation is timing. The bindings in ListView and DataGrid might get created later than those in the ItemsControl, i.e. after _CreateWizardSteps() was called. In case _CreateWizardSteps()  is only called once on startup, you may probably just set the DataContext after calling _CreateWizardSteps().