# Is there any way to bind a variable to another variable? (WPF Project)

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, binding

I have set a border visibility binding to a variable in a class in Views, called P, where P is a Boolean type. I have another variable in a class in ViewModels, called M, where M is a Dictionary and the Enum consists of three elements, something like A, B and C. How could I bind P to M.value in which if P is false, M.value is set to A, and if P is true, M.value is set to B or C (depends on some condition) so that the border is visible when M.value is B or C and it is not visible when M.value is A?

So far I have implemented binding of border visibility to P already and it works (when P is true, it is visible and when P is false, it is not visible).

```cs
enum E {
        A,B,C
}

public class ClassInViews {
    private bool picked = false;
    public bool Picked {get; set;}
}

public class ClassInViewModels {

    private Dictionary<(...An arbitrary class in Models),E> M;
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to bind it to changes of the Dictionary, I would then use an [ObservableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616554/observabledictionary-for-c-sharp) and respond to any change within the collection by raising a changed event for the "Picked" property. So your ViewModel has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Then the simplest thing would be to write your logic into the getter of P.

```
public bool Picked 
{
  get
  {
    /*Your logic here*/
  }
}
```

Second Option: You could create an IValueConverter transforming your given Directory to a Visibility.

```
public class Bool2VisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        static Bool2VisibilityConverter _converter;

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (_converter == null)
            {
                _converter = new Bool2VisibilityConverter();
            }
            return _converter;
        }

        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dic = value as ObservableDictionaray<YourTypesHere>;

            if (dic == null)
              return Visibility.Collapsed;


            bool visible = /* Check the Dictionary with your logic */;

            return (bool) visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementexException();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Then you can simply use it to transform the Dictionary:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Dictioanry, Converter={conv:Bool2VisibilityConverter}}" />
```