# C# WPF ObservableCollection with dictionary inside to MVVM Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, mvvm, datagrid

The problem is solved, Insted of using a dictionary I "converted" it to an OS (ObservableCollection) and bound it to a Datagrid inside the DatagridTemplateColumn

I am trying to add my ObservableCollaction which have a property `Name` and a dictionary with the properties: `Name`, `AvgPrice` and `Shares`.

How do I get the `Name`, `AvgPrice` and `Shares` inside the dictionary to a **DataGrid**?

The ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<WatchlistModel> _watchlists;
public ObservableCollection<WatchlistModel> Watchlists
{
    get { return _watchlists; }
    set { _watchlists = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

The WatchlistModel

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { if(_name != value) { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
}

private Dictionary<string, StockModel> _stocks;
public Dictionary<string, StockModel> Stocks
{
    get { return _stocks; }
    set { if (_stocks != value) { _stocks = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

The Datagrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Watchlists, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Average Price" Binding="{Binding Path=AvgPrice}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shares" Binding="{Binding Path=Shares}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Json format

```
{
  "name": "My Watchlist",
  "stocks": {
    "Zaptec": {
      "avgPrice": "2,14",
      "name": "Zaptec",
      "shares": 121
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to display all *stocks*  in the same `DataGrid` rather than all stock lists?

Comment: @mm8 Melkor V helped me to solve this on Discord. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
<!-- Here you can add items control or whatever and bound its ItemSource to your 
Stocks -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But I don't recommend you to use Dictionary. Make ObservableCollection instead. It's pretty hard to Bind Dictionary<key, val> with observe on Items changed.

Comment: Hello, the person who helped me with the dictionary told me that I have to use it... I made an edit and added the json format. It comes from firebase

Comment: U have a better way to deserialize it?

Comment: U can deserialize it in your StockModel, but create straighten class which contains that string (key) inside that class...

Comment: I do not think I understand what u mean unfortunately. You have an example?

Comment: Yeah it would be little messy, but it would be work without creating custom Dictionary which will Observe items change. But if you need exactly this Dictionary as reference - paste any Control with ItemSource property inside that comment section and use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616554/observabledictionary-for-c-sharp

Comment: I mean just create new class with all properties from StockModel plus your key(string) from that Dictionary. Make ObservableCollection, add all StockModel objects into new Objects and insert them into ObservableCollection.

Comment: For example MyNewStockModel = new MyNewStockModel () { key = StockModel.key,  avgPrice = StockModel[key].avgPrice, name = StockModel[key].Name, shares = StockModel[key].shares }

Comment: Then after your Stocks Dictionary created and filled with info - Fill your ObservableCollection<MyNewStockModel> with info from Stocks...

Comment: So you mean that I should create a ObservableCollection inside WatchlistModel?

Comment: @Gnusson exactly

Comment: Ok, so how do I fill the MyNewStockModel?

Comment: var observable = firebase.Child("users/" + _userService.GetUid()).AsObservable<WHAT CLASS SHOULD BE HERE?>().Subscribe(d =>

Comment: @Gnusson just get info from your Stocks Dictionary. Whenever you add new item to that dictionary - make sure to creane new MyNewStockModel with data from that camed to Stocks Dictionary - new object

Comment: Yes but I cannot Deserialize JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WatchlistModel>(json) Because this gives me an error

Comment: U have Discord or any other chat applications? Its hard to have a discussion here..

Comment: @Gnusson add [JsonIgnore] to ObservableCollection. When Deserialization ends - fill ObservableCollection with data

Comment: @Gnusson Timur#0378 Discord