# Accessing XAML object in codebehind(WPF)

Tags: wpf

I'm creating object in XAML like this

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:DataReceiver x:Key="request">
        </local:DataReceiver>
    </Window.Resources>
```

how can I call this objects method from codebehind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing codebehind object in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244616/accessing-codebehind-object-in-xaml)

Answer (score 1):

```
DataReceiver request = this.TryFindResource("request") as DataReceiver;
if (request != null)
{
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: Should probably be 'as DataReceiver' rather than 'as Style' :-)

Comment: problem is that i need to call exactly methode of the object that i created in xlm, without creating new one =\

Comment: ZAA - this finds the exact object that was instantiated in XAML.

Comment: strange cuz my bindings at null? so i sopose that different object =\

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataReceiver = (DataReceiver)FindResource("request");
...
```