# WPF reference object from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is one that bothers me!

I found on stackoverflow this [Accessing XAML object in codebehind(WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703431/accessing-xaml-object-in-codebehindwpf) about accessing a resource.

But what if i want reference to a textbox, for example, in my code-behind file?
I didn't find that around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it an `x:Name` and then in your code-behind just reference it as `this.TheName`.

See [XAML Named Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#x_name_and_xaml_named_elements) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox"  Text="Example Text"/>
```

Code:

```
  txtBox.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

But not all objects in xaml has property called `Name`, in that case you can use this:

```
<SomeObject x:Name="namedObject" .../>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do that. In my case i need to FindName and then cast. That sounds like ASP.Net, as I would have expected.

Comment: @Andrei: You can do that. Try doing it!