# WPF Binding to local variable

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

Can you bind to a local variable like this?

**SystemDataBase.cs**

```
namespace WebWalker
{
    public partial class SystemDataBase : Window
    {
        private string text = "testing";
...
```

**SystemDataBase.xaml**

```
 <TextBox 
       Name="stbSQLConnectionString" 
       Text="{SystemDataBase.text}">
 </TextBox>
```

??

Text is set to the local variable "text"

Answer (score 42):

The pattern is:

```
public string Text {get;set;}
```

and the binding is

```
{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}
```

If you want the binding to update automatically you should make it a DependencyProperty.

---

I think 3.5 added `ElementName` to bindings, so the following is a little easier:

```
<Window x:Name="Derp" ...
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Derp}"/>
```

Comment: Or have the class implement INotifyPropertyChanged to have the binding work automatically.

Comment: I think you mean change it to a DependencyProperty.  Implementing INPC on a DependencyObject would be foolish.

Comment: Come to think of it, what is ElementName in this case? The name of the Window?

Comment: @killianmcc: Its right in the code sample.  `<Window Name="Derp"`  Where `Derp` is a (at least how I normally do it) DependencyProperty defined on your window class (`public partial class Herp : Window {}`)

Answer (score 29):

To bind to a local "variable" the variable should be:

1. A property, not a field.
2. Public.
3. Either a notifying property (suitable for model classes) or a dependency property (sutable for view classes)

Notifying property example:

```
public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void PropertyType myField;

    public PropertyType MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myField;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.myField)
            {
                this.myField = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Dependency property example:

```
public MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public PropertyType MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (PropertyType)GetValue("MyProperty");
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("MyProperty", value);
        }
    }

    // Look up DependencyProperty in MSDN for details
    public static DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you're doing a lot of this, you could consider binding the DataContext of the whole window to your class.  This will be inherited by default, but can still be overridden as usual

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Then for an individual components you can use

```
Text="{Binding Text}"
```

Comment: I know this question is for WPF, but If your target is Silverlight then this the way to go.. Since Silverlight for Web and Phone does not have FindAncestor method for RelativeSource

Answer (score 3):

To bind a local variable which is present in your Window class it has to be :
1. Public property
2. A notifying property. For this your window class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for this property.

Then in the constructor

```
public Assgn5()
{           
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this; // or **stbSQLConnectionString**.DataContext = this;
}

 <TextBox 
   Name="stbSQLConnectionString" 
   Text="{Binding text}">
 </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the following line in the int constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

And use this in the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text = "{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

Exmaple:

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        PersonName = "default";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show($"Hello {PersonName}");
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="textbox1" 
                 Text="{Binding PersonName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 />
        <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" Content="Click Me" />
</StackPanel>
```