# changing custom control textblock value by code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, controltemplate

I am learning how to write a windows 8 app, and I can't find any answers to my problem.

I created a custom control where I am adding by a button click with:

```
onclick() {
    card currentcard = new card();
    ...
    ...
    hand.Children.add(currentCard);
}
```

in page.cs

The current card control has Generic.xaml information that looks like this containing a `TextBlock`

```
<Style TargetType="local:tile">
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:tile">
        <Border
             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <TextBlock x:Name="Label"/> // <----------------------- this textblock
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

What can I do to in page.cs or perhaps card.cs to get/set value of `TextBlock` named Label?

Sorry if this is elementary or answered somewhere before, I did searches, but I didn't find my answer!

Comment: If you want to set the value of the textblock in code, you need to use wpf data binding. Kind of like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4344584/299327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `TextBlock` in question is a part of a `ControlTemplate` for a custom type called Tile, your best bet for this will be to add a `DependencyProperty` to your Tile type and use `TemplateBinding` to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to the value of this new `DependencyProperty`.

You cannot easily reach into a `ControlTemplate` from the outside to modify the value of a part of that template.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088906/adding-a-custom-dependency-property-to-a-control-template-in-xaml) provides one example of using a `DependencyProperty` and binding it to a `ControlTemplate`, and a quick search will probably yield many other examples.

Comment: ooh thanks i'll look into that. sorry if I knew about DependencyProperty I would have looked it up. Thanks for pulling that up for me!

Comment: Glad to help.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) is the MSDN article on DependencyProperties.  If you feel this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.