# Databinding a variable in C# to a textblock in a WPF application not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML, C# novice and am struggling to databind a variable defined in my code behind to a textblock defined in XAML. But I get not result.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="totalRecording">
                        <Run Text="44 /"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Source=listlength, Path=totalRecording}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Here is my code behind

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listlength = 100;
    }
}
}
```

For now I have just set the variable to a static number for the purposes of illustrating my problem but this variable will be obtained from a list Count value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Binding to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable)

Comment: You are not implementing the necessary data binding notifications that the textblock requires.

Comment: To begin with WPF binding I recommend you to start with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part or some other tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Eugene I will have a look a that tutorial you linked

Comment: @ocajian It is always a good idea to read some basic tutorials before plunging into the practice. It will save you from many mistakes and blunders. Good luck.

Comment: So @Sajeetharan is my code fine up to the point where I need to use INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @EugenePodskal the thing is I have read some tutorials from Microsoft on the topic but still struggle with this...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For binding you need to use **Property** only .you cannot use varibale for binding.

To create property I have created a class here . It is not necessary to create a new class to have property.

```
  public class TextboxText
{
    public string textdata { get; set; }

}
```

And set  datacontext to textblock so that I can use this property for binding

```
InitializeComponent();
totalRecording.DataContext = new TextboxText() { textdata = "100" };
```

in xaml

```
<Grid Height="300" Width="400" Background="Red">
    <TextBlock Name="totalRecording">
       <Run Text="44 /"/>
       <Run Text="{Binding textdata}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! So I see the problem is that you can't pass a variable in a databind. Thanks for helping! Much appreciated.

Comment: Do I really have to create another class for the context? Is there not a simpler way to do this?

Comment: and when the data is changing? I mean I have this simple button that updates a string, just so I can learn data binding with wpf, how can I do that? or should I ask a different question (or is there one out there?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **update** the Binding, you should use a **DependencyProperty**.

First you have to create the **property** and a **public string** like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ListLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ListLength", typeof(string), typeof(Window), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string ListLength
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ListLengthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListLengthProperty, value); }
    }
```

Here is the **XAML** file, you need to set a **name** for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="CurrentWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="totalRecording">
                    <Run Text="44 /"/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding ListLength, ElementName=CurrentWindow}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Now you can always update the Binding by setting the **ListLength** like this:

```
ListLength = "100";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use TextBlock,

```
     <Grid Name="myGrid" Height="437.274">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=listlength}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Declare the variable and Implement [`InotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

```
    partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private string _listlength;

      public string Listlength
      {
        get { return _listlength; }
        set
        {
          if (value != _listlength)
          {
             _listlength = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Listlength");
          }
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: in the xaml, should the listlength be Listlength?