# Binding textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have implemented the binding using the answer posted here: [WPF Binding to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable)
and this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

It looks like this:

```
public partial class AddCard: DXWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private int _CardNumber;

   public int CardNumber
   { 
       get { return _CardNumber; }
       set
       {
           if (value != _CardNumber)
           {
              _CardNumber = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("CardNumber");
           }
       }
   }

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
   }
}
```

in xaml (I'm using DevExpress components):

```
    <dx:DXWindow
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    .../>

<dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding Path=CardNumber}"/>
```

The problem:
When updating the CardNumber value in code - it updates the text box on the window, BUT updating the textbox in the window - doesn't update the property of CardNumber in code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default updates only propagate through when the control loses focus. I suspect you want them to update immediately, in which case add 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged' to your binding.