# Set property in custom class with dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom class with some properties.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In a `UserControl` I have added a Dependency Property to the custom class.

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Person1Property = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        nameof(Person1),
        typeof(Person),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, Person1Changed)
    );

    public Person Person1
    {
        get { return (Person) GetValue(Person1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Person1Property, value); }
    }

    static void Person1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue && d is MyUserControl)
        {
            var instance = d as MyUserControl;
            instance.Person1 = e.NewValue as Person;
        }
    }
}
```

**In the MainWindow.xaml I would like to do:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <local:MyUserControl
        Person1.Name="{Binding SomeNameInViewModel}"
        Person1.Age="{Biding SomeAgeInViewModel}"
    />

</Window>
```

But that didn't work :(
I can only do:

```
<Window>
    <local:MyUserControl Person1="{Binding Person1InViewModel}" />
</Window>
```

I started to think if this is even possible. **But then I thought of the DockPanel:**

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <Label DockPanel.Dock=Right" />
</DockPanel>
```

Is there a solution to access a class property in XAML via Dependency Property?

Comment: Why not have a Person property in the view mode? BTW: setting `instance.Person1` in `Person1Changed` is not useful at all - the DP has already been set to the new value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483837/38368

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Binding to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable)

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
I already know how to use the INotificationPropertychanged interface.I ignored all reference of it in my post to not clutter the example.

Answer (score 1):

The bindings do not work, because the binding target [must be a dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#basic-data-binding-concepts).

> **The target property must be a dependency property**. Most `UIElement` properties are dependency properties, and most dependency properties, except read-only ones, support data binding by default. (Only types derived from `DependencyObject` can define dependency properties; and all `UIElement` types derive from `DependencyObject`.)

Since `Person1Property` with its getter and setter is a dependency property, this works.

```
<local:MyUserControl Person1="{Bidning AnyPersonInstance}" />
```

However, `Name` and `Age` are **regular CLR properties** defined on the `Person` class, which is not a `DependencyObject` (and therefore cannot even define dependency properties as stated above).

```
<local:MyUserControl Person1.Name="{Binding SomeNameInViewModel}"
                     Person1.Age="{Biding SomeAgeInViewModel}"/>
```

Of course, you could expose explicit `Name` and `Age` dependency properties on `MyUserControl` instead of `Person1`, but you do not even have to do that.

You can simply bind a `Person` instance from your view model and bind its `Name` and `Age` properties. They will be properly updated if you bind them in two-way mode. There is not need at all to define other dependency properties or the `Person1Changed` since it is redundant then. In any case, you should [implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) in your `Person` type if you bind its properties, so that the user interface gets notified of changes to these properties and the bindings are updated.

```
<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
```

Regarding the `Dock` property, this is a so-called [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and is used for different reasons.

> An attached property is a concept defined by XAML. An attached property is **intended to be used as a type of global property that is settable on any object**. In Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), attached properties are typically defined as a specialized form of dependency property that does not have the conventional property "wrapper".

> One purpose of an attached property is to allow different child elements to specify unique values for a property that's defined in a parent element. A specific application of this scenario is having child elements inform the parent element of how they are to be presented in the user interface (UI). One example is the `DockPanel.Dock` property. The `DockPanel.Dock` property is created as an attached property because it is designed to be set on elements that are contained within a `DockPanel` rather than on `DockPanel` itself. The `DockPanel` class defines the static `DependencyProperty` field named `DockProperty`, and then provides the `GetDock` and `SetDock` methods as public accessors for the attached property.

Comment: Thank you @thatguy for such a detailed answer.
In my post I ignored all INotificationPropertyChanged since it clutter the example code.
I will consider binding to the Person1 dependency property. That is a good solution, but not an optimal solution for my actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I started to think if this is even possible

You're right. It's *not* possible to set the `Name` property of the `Person` object returned by the `Person1` dependency property like this in XAML:

```
<local:MyUserControl
    Person1.Name="{Binding SomeNameInViewModel}" />
```

> But then I thought of the DockPanel

`DockPanel.Dock` is an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). You are not setting the `Dock` property of an object returned from a `DockPanel` object. You are setting an attached `Dock` property.

So if you want to be able to set `Person1.Name` and `Person1.Age` in the XAML markup, you should define two separate attached properties called `Name` and `Age` in a type called `Person1`.

You cannot solve this using a single `Person` dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how much this will help you, but you can use a special external class to bindings to CLR properties.

An example of a similar class:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Common.Proxy
{
    public class ProxyBridge : Freezable
    {
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
            => new ProxyBridge();


        /// <summary>The binding source.</summary>
        public object Source
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="Source"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Source), typeof(object), typeof(ProxyBridge), new PropertyMetadata(null, SourceChanged));

        private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ProxyBridge)d).Target = e.NewValue;
        }


        /// <summary>The binding target.</summary>
        public object Target
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> для свойства <see cref="Target"/>.</summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Target), typeof(object), typeof(ProxyBridge), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    }
}
```

An example of its use:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <local:Person x:Key="person" Name="Alex" Age="35"/>
        <proxy:ProxyBridge x:Key="bridgeName"
                           Target="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource person}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                           Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbName}"/>
        <proxy:ProxyBridge x:Key="bridgeAge" 
                           Target="{Binding Age, Source={StaticResource person}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                           Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbAge}"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource person}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, Source={StaticResource person}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Target, Source={StaticResource bridgeName}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Target, Source={StaticResource bridgeAge}}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbName"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbAge"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

This class has application features.

If you are interested in such a solution, then I will write about them.