# How to declare a decimal value in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, decimal

I'm able to declare an integer or double value in xaml. However, I can't add a decimal value. It builds ok, but then I get:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The type 'Decimal' was not
>   found.

Here's the xaml code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <system:Int32 x:Key="AnIntValue">1000</system:Int32><!--Works!-->
    <system:Double x:Key="ADoubleValue">1000.0</system:Double><!--Works!-->
    <system:Decimal x:Key="ADecimalValue">1000.0</system:Decimal><!--Fails at runtime-->
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here's how I'm declaring the system namespace:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

**Edit: Workaround:**
As Steven mentioned, adding the resource through code-behind seems to work fine:

```
Resources.Add("ADecimalValue", new Decimal(1000.0));
```

**Edit: Answer:**
Doing exactly the same thing in WPF seems to work fine. So I guess this is a hidden silverlight restriction. Thanks to Steven for this finding.

Comment: How are you trying to use this resource in the xaml?

Comment: I use it in a converter parameter for a binding. I'm referencing it as a static resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed your finding that the Decimal type does not appear to work as a static resource in a UserControl's resources section. I do however see a couple workarounds that have been discussed here on StackOverflow, and that i have just personally verified to work with the Decimal type in Silverlight: [Access codebehind variable in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666856/access-codebehind-variable-in-xaml)

The workarounds include:

- adding the resource from the code-behind (see the link above)
- Referencing a property in the code behind using an "elementname" type binding
- Accessing a public Decimal property on the user controls data context property.

The second workaround can be done like this:

```
<sdk:Label Name="label1" Content="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DecimalProperty}" />
```

...where the root usercontrol tag is defined like this (this idea is from the link above also):

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightDecimal.MainPage" x:Name="root" .... >
```

and this is in your user control's code-behind:

```
public decimal DecimalProperty
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
    set
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first workaround actually worked. Now I'm looking for an explanation on why I can't declare the resource in XAML.

Comment: I'm glad the workaround worked. Google does not seem to have the answer and i am starting to wonder if it is a bug. From the information i have seen, the type Decimal is contained in mscorlib.dll which is automatically referenced by silverlight projects. Doing pre/post build events to manually make sure that dll was in the build output directory also did not help.

Comment: I made a bare bones WPF project and it was perfectly happy with Decimal as a static resource, how strange.

Comment: Ahh, so this might be a hidden silverlight restriction, meaning that my xaml was ok. That's good to know!